# Angular ui router -pass stateParams to other controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is part of my state provider:

```
  $stateProvider.state('root', {
         url: '',
          abstract: true,
          templateUrl: viewsRoot + "layout.html",
          controller: 'LayoutController',
           views: {
          'container': {
            templateUrl: viewsRoot + "container.html",

          },
          'sidebar': {
                 templateUrl: viewsRoot + "sidebar.html",
                 controller: 'SidebarController'

          }
       }
      })
      .state('layout.sidebar', {
          abstract: true,
          templateUrl: viewsRoot + "sidebar.html",
          controller: 'SidebarController'
      })
          .state('layout.container', {
              abstract: true,
              templateUrl: viewsRoot + "container.html",
            //  controller: 'ObjectDetailsController' 
          })
          .state('root.object-details', {
              url:'object-details/:objectId',
              templateUrl: viewsRoot + "object-details.html",
              controller: 'ObjectDetailsController',
```

Some content on sidebar should change depending on objectId. I can access  `$stateParams.objectId` in `ObjectDetailsController`  but I would like to access them in sidebar controller. Maybe pass them to parent, and then parent should pass value to sidebar.

Comment: You can make one field in parent scope or rootscope that store current object id and on change of page update that field with new value .And then you can easily access that variable in your side bar controller also.

Comment: assign $stateParams.objectId value to $rootscope.. There are also other ways like $broadcast, angular services.

Comment: SidebarController is executed before everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to pass the data via the `params` options in `$stateProvider`?

[The API can be found here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider).

So your code can look like this:

```
.state('layout.sidebar', {
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: viewsRoot + "sidebar.html",
  controller: 'SidebarController',
  params: {id: 'value'}
})
```

You can pass the param inside the view:

```
<a ui-sref="layout.sidebar({id: 'object.Id'})></a>
```

Comment: I'm trying to get objectId from child states inside sidebar so can sidebar can have link for example to root.object-details(objectId) ,root-object-images(objectId)

Comment: Well, you pass the object to the controller. If you have child elements from sidebar, they inherit from this scope/controller, so you have access to them. Your app routing seems quite complex. Maybe think of architectural re-buildings to make it easier to understand/handle?